# Adaptive Card show text input block based on choice set value in microsoft teams using bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a card with input choice set of options a,b,others.

If users selects option as "others" then an extra input text block should come below the choice set.

How can we achieve this in microsoft teams bot framework using adaptive cards?

Comment: Please refer below thread which addresses similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393706/adaptive-card-show-text-input-block-based-on-choice-set-value

Comment: That is in webchat. How to implement same in teams using adaptive cards templating?

Comment: Cascading dropdown list doesn't seem to be feasible at the moment. Alternative you can use Action.ToggleVisibility (action that toggles the visibility of associated card elements). Ref: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ToggleVisibility.html