# client side validation in adaptive cards templating in c#

Tags: json, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards, web-chat

Basic validation like input type is not working on emulator nor on web chat. I am using .net core in bot framework and adaptive card v1.2 templating. Validation like isRequired and errorMessage is available in adaptive cards v1.3 but it is not supported in web chat. How do I get client side validation in adaptive cards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Input text a required field in adaptive card version 1.2 for webchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808224/how-do-i-make-input-text-a-required-field-in-adaptive-card-version-1-2-for-webch)

Comment: Yes. Thanks a ton. This works.

Comment: Hi Kyle, a quick question on the 'validation' proto schema, is there a way to change the font color/size of the error message.

Comment: That was asked in the other question. It should be achievable with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can use to get client-side validation to work in Web Chat, as seen in this answer: [How do I make Input text a required field in adaptive card version 1.2 for webchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808224/how-do-i-make-input-text-a-required-field-in-adaptive-card-version-1-2-for-webch/63855614#63855614)

> While examining the source code for version 1.2.6, I came across some
> secret required-input code that was probably just meant for testing
> purposes but actually does work in Web Chat. That proto-schema looks
> like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "type": "Input.Text",
>   "id": "firstName",
>   "placeholder": "First Name",
>   "validation": {
>     "necessity": "Required",
>     "errorMessage": "First Name is required"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If that works for you then great, but if you want more control or if
> you happen to be using an even earlier version of Adaptive Cards then
> you'll need the rest of this answer.
>
> When you talk about making an input field "required" it seems like you
> want these two behaviors when a submit action is clicked and the field
> is empty:
>
> 1. You want the submit action to not be processed
> 2. You want an error message to be displayed
>
> Web Chat specifies an action handler for each Adaptive Card it creates
> and there's no easy way to override that, so for behavior #1 your best
> option is to have your bot check the incoming inputs and short-circuit
> its logic if a required input is missing.
>
> For behavior #2, you could also handle that on the bot side by having
> the bot send a message back to Web Chat that lets the user know which
> inputs are missing from the Adaptive Card. Alternatively, you could
> send a new card with an additional text block next to each input field
> that wasn't populated in the first card.
>
> If you really want to toggle those text blocks on the Web Chat side
> then there may actually be a way to do that. Even if you can't
> override Web Chat's submit action behavior, you can add to the
> behavior by providing an `onExecute` handler for each action. You'll
> have to read this answer for an explanation of how to apply special
> Adaptive Card functionality in Web Chat:
> [BotFramework-WebChat - Adaptive Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877533/botframework-webchat-adaptive-card/61621137#61621137)